# Junit + maven , Include test packages for parallel execution at runtime in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, junit, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

I am able to do parallel execution by using

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <configuration>
      <parallel>classes</parallel>
       <forkCount>3</forkCount>
      <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
      <includes>
        <include>**/Test_package1_*.class</include>
      </includes>
      <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Similary i need to execute other set of packages parallely , So is there a way to update pom.xml at runtime for updating  with different set of package.

Can somebody help me on this

Comment: Have you tried defining multiple `executions` within the plugin definition, each with their own configuration? Does that not achieve what you want?

Comment: got the solution by using <profiles> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959211/maven-surefire-plugin-include-exclude-precedence]